# How do I invoke wow64 manually?

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit

On Windows 7, I have an application that can't run in 64 bit. How do I invoke `wow64` manually? Compatibility mode does not work, nor does pasting it into `C:/Program Files (x86)/`.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot. If the .exe file is marked as "x64", Windows will run it in 64-bit mode. If the .exe is marked as "x32", it will be run in 32-bit mode using *wow64*. Having "an application that can't run in 64-bit" doesn't make much sense, as 32-bit programs are *never* run directly in 64-bit mode.

A more specific problem description than just "can't run" would be helpful.

Comment: When I run the executable it pops up with the following error:

[Content]
The version of this file is not compatible with the version of Windows you're running. Check your computer's system information to see whether you need an x86 (32-bit) or x64 (64-bit) version of the program, and then contact the software publisher.

[OK]

Comment: which executible is that?

Comment: What kind of executable is it? x64, 32-bit x86, or perhaps 16-bit? (Note that 16-bit programs *cannot* be run directly on a 64-bit OS.)

Comment: It could be that the EXE file is broken. Try to get the same file again.

Comment: I had the same issue with a game called Rampart. It's an old Midway Arcade Game. Someone had made a version of it that looks like the arcade. I thought the same, 32 bit possibly. But the game was made in 1994. After I read the post about it possibly being a 16 bit exe; well, "Occums' Razor" can fill the rest. Cheers!